Giving the base of the triangle as a function of some other lenght.
How do you connect c to AB (writing AB as some function of c)


Give more details about the figure. Give a mathematical description of the problem.

Two identical circles inscribed in ABC. The smaller triangle's sides are defined to be lines from C through the tangency point of the line (that cuts the triangle into two similar triangles) and the tops of the circles.
